# MultiConnection using a WhatsApp API

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, whatsapp

I'm working in a project and I'd like to know if is there any package or API or something using JavaScript (Node.js) that can handle a MultiConnection and reconnection. For example, I was using WhatsApp-web.js, that you can connect your phone scanning a QR, the problem is or the problem I got was I can't do reconnects of multiple devices, so every time I restart the system, I have to request the QR, scan, and connect. I'm looking a way to just scan once and then, when I restart the system, my phone can be still connected.

I know whatsapp-web.js has a way to handle some connections, but I want an undefined amount, I mean, if I'd like 5 connections, my system can handle them and reconnect them when I restart.

I tried using whatsapp-web.js but the only way I saw I can reconnect is just a single connection, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: whatsapp-web.js is a _"WhatsApp client library for NodeJS that connects through the WhatsApp Web browser app"_ - and the WhatsApp Web browser app does not let you connect to multiple devices at the same time, AFAIK. So any other library using that technique, would have the same issue. Not sure what _exactly_ you want to achieve here to begin with; maybe(!) it could be solved by using different browser profiles, where you stay logged in to WhatsApp Web with one account in each profile ...